# alguien que me diga porque me sale este error al conectar php soap con un servidor web

Tags: php, xampp, soap, server

En este caso se describe la implementación en PHP de un cliente que utiliza un Web-Service haciendo uso igualmente del archivo de descripción WSDL.
estoy usando xampp pero al ponerlo en el navegador me aparece un error que no se como solucionar, alguien que me pueda ayudar con eso porfa...................................................................................................................................................................................................................
el codigo es el siguiente

```
   // Cargar las librerias.

   require_once('./lib/nusoap.php');

   // Produccion

   $wsdl="http://b5m.gipuzkoa.eus/ws/dfg-dibujar-context-root/DibujarSoapHttpPort?WSDL";

   // Leer el WSDL y crear los proxys

   $client=new soapclient($wsdl, 'wsdl');

   // Cambiar el endpoint URL a $wsdl menos los ultimos 5 chars

   $client->operations['mapasdisponibles']['endpoint'] = substr($wsdl,0,strlen($wsdl)-5);

   // Forzar los char sets.

   $client->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';

   $client->decode_utf8 = false;

   // Ejemplo de parametros

   $params1=array(array('categoria'=>'PUBLI','lengua'=>'0'));

   // A poco de comprobacion de errores.

   $err = $client->getError();

   if ($err) {

         echo 'Constructor error' . $err ;

   }

   // LLamar al SOAP API.

   $result = $client->call('mapasdisponibles', $params1);

   if ($client->fault)

   {

          echo 'Fault'; print_r($result);

   }

   else

   {

           $err = $client->getError();

           if ($err)

          {

             echo 'Error' . $err ;

          }

   else

   {

             // Ver los resultados

              print_r( $result ) ;

          }

   }

   ?>
```

estoy usando xampp pero al abrirlo en el navegador me aparece  este error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: por lo que se ve en el error no se pudo establecer una conexion, verifica la url de conexion y la forma en que haces la conexion

Comment: Prueba con `curl http://b5m.gipuzkoa.eus/ws/dfg-dibujar-context-root/DibujarSoapHttpPort?WSDL` desde la línea de comandos a ver qué te devuelve. De hecho, ¿por qué dice 192.168.160.41:8888? ¿Cómo se traduce b5m.gipuzkoa.eus en esa ip:puerto?